# Intercepting aspect for custom annotion

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, spring-aop, pointcut

I am writing a library/sdk which can intercept any methods which are annotated with a custom annotation `@Monitor`.
The code works somewhat like this

```
@Monitor
public void methodA(String test)
```

And the aspect which intercepts this has this pointcut expression

```
@After("execution(@com.packageA.Monitor * *(..))")
public void intercept(final JoinPoint joinPoint){
...}
```

This code works fine when I describe the aspect in the same package as the `methodA`. However if I create a separate library and define the aspect in that its not able to intercept the `methodA` . Any help?

### EDIT

In response to @Bond's comment

```
@Component
@Target(value = {ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Monitor {

}
```

Spring versions:
spring-context - 4.1.7.Release
aspectj - 1.6.5
The crux of the problem is that the annotation wont be used in the same project. After compilation it will be used in a different project all together.

### EDIT2

The 2nd project i.e the one from which this aspect should be intercepting is compiled using aspectj maven plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the pointcut to `@annotation(com.x.y.z.Monitor)`. (*correct the package name accordingly*)

Thus your aspect should look something like below

```
@After("@annotation(com.x.y.z.Monitor)") 
public void intercept(final JoinPoint joinPoint){
    ...
}
```

*Have a look at [examples](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-examples) for reference about various pointcut expressions available. Also read [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-params-names) in case advise accepts argument(s)*

Comment: On trying your approach it is still not able to intercept that method. Plus its throws a warning in eclipse like this `advice defined in com.x.y.AspectName has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]`

Comment: okies.. please update the question with relevant configs, spring version and `@Monitor` annotations' definition. Also post the complete error / warning logs.